# Attaching an event handler multiple times

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, events, delegates

I am new to C#. I just wanted to know whether attaching event handler multiple times can cause unexpected result?

Actually in my application i am attaching an event handler to an event like

```
cr.ListControlPart.Grid.CurrentCellActivated += new EventHandler(Grid_CurrentCellActivated);
```

and this line of code called multiple times in the code.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you keep attaching event handlers then it will be raised once for each time you've attached the handler. This means:

- If you only need it to be raised once then assign one handler.
- If you attach the same handler 4 times then it will be called 4 times.

Looking at your code, instead of hooking into the `CurrentCellActivated` event multiple times it would make more sense to subscribe to a general `CellActivated` event once.

Comment: It means if event handler attached 10 times then whenever event raised then handler get called 10 times?

Comment: @Jamse actually i am playing with dropdown grid of grid cell. and there is no event like "CellActivated".

Comment: "each instance" is ambiguous.  If you subscribe 12 times with the same handler instance then it will be called 12 times when the event fires.

Comment: @BillTarbell yeah, poor wording in hindsight, feel free to edit :)

Answer (score 39):

Try it yourself:

```
static class Program
{
    static event EventHandler MyEvent;

    static void Main()
    {
        // registering event
        MyEvent += Program_MyEvent;
        MyEvent += Program_MyEvent;
        MyEvent += Program_MyEvent;
        MyEvent += Program_MyEvent;
        MyEvent += Program_MyEvent;

        // invoke event
        MyEvent(null, EventArgs.Empty);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static void Program_MyEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("MyEvent fired");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
MyEvent fired
MyEvent fired
MyEvent fired
MyEvent fired
MyEvent fired
```

Comment: It will call the event multiple times.

Answer (score 26):

You can prevent it by unsubscribing before adding it,

```
Object.Event -= EventHandler(method);
Object.Event += EventHandler(method);
```

if can be done, prevent it by always subscribe events in one place say constructor

Comment: What will happen when we try to unsubscribe event handler first time when it is not subscribed yet?

Comment: @Bhushan Yes, even it is best practice to unsubscribe event when not in use. GC Will not collect this immediately

Comment: This approach works and no exceptions are raised on the first subscription. (i.e. the -= is silently ignored).

Comment: So long as you keep a handle to the original function around, you're good. This doesn't work so well for the anonymous method declared using a lambda or the `new` keyword ;)